# How to improve reading speed from a file?

Tags: c++

I am reading from a txt file that contains roughly 1.7 million lines where each line consists of 3 integers. The problem that I am facing is that it takes me approximately 30 sec to loop through and store integers in a vector.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
std::ifstream finVertices("Phantom Data/FA_vertices.txt", std::ios::in);
    if (!finVertices)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can not open verticies.txt" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Loading verticies" << std::endl;

    std::string verticesLineBuffer;
    while (std::getline(finVertices, verticesLineBuffer))
    {
        std::istringstream voxelStringCoordinates(verticesLineBuffer);
        GLfloat x, y, z;
        voxelStringCoordinates >> x >> y >> z;
        vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(y, z, x));
    }

    finVertices.close();
```

Example of txt file content:

```
297 13 164
297 13 165
297 14 164
297 14 165
298 13 164
298 13 165
```

Question: How can I improve reading process from a txt file?

EDIT: Thank you for help. With your help I managed to solve the problem. 
Here is the code:

```
std::ifstream is(fileName, std::ifstream::binary);

    if (is) {
        is.seekg(0, is.end);
        int length = is.tellg();
        is.seekg(0, is.beg);

        char* buffer = new char[length];

        is.read(buffer, length);

        is.close();

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < is.gcount(); i++)
        {
            // here can get access to each indiviual character
        }
```

Comment: `push_back` could be part of your problem. If you have an idea how many veritcies you have reserve that when you create your vector.

Comment: Does `vertices` have sufficient reserved size so it doesn't have to reallocate?

Comment: `iostreams` are models of inefficiency. You don't want to use `iostreams` or `std::string`s when speed matters. I would use `mmap` to map the whole file in memory, then iterate over it, using `std::from_chars` to rip out the integer values, one by one.

Comment: Why do you use a stringstream instead of reading directly from the file?

Comment: As Jesper pointed out, your build settings are important here. What were those? Can you increase optimisation?

Comment: `voxelStringCoordinates >> x >> y >> z;` should be `if (!(voxelStringCoordinates >> x >> y >> z)) throw "oopsies";`

Comment: @Eljay no it does not have reserved size. It  depends on the object type. Each object has different amount of vertices.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, my bad I did not think that it will affect performance.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik , thank you for suggestion. I will try to use mmap.

Comment: @Elnur see if you can use the file size as some heuristic to indicate some reasonable upper bound of elements that exist in the file. Even better, if you have control over the file format, make the first line of the file be meta information, such as how many lines it contains. Then you'll know how large to reserve your vector.

Comment: Background:  Your bottlenecks are the reading from the file and the translating of the data.  You can reduce the bottleneck by increasing the data transferred per transaction.  For example, one request of 1024 bytes is more efficient than 1024 requests of one byte.  Try to keep the file reading streaming; stopping and starting wastes execution time.  You may want to use a separate thread for reading into buffers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you, but I managed to solve the problem by reading entire file.

Answer (score 4):

1) read larger chunks at a time. Like 1MiB or 10MiB or the entire file in one go. Then process the data from the memory you read the file (or chunk) into. Or `mmap` the file.

2) call `reserve()` on your `vertices` vector before adding to it to reduce the number of allocations it has to make.

3) compile your code with optimizations enabled (aka release build).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsetbuf has an example of increasing the `ifstream` buffer size.